# Continuity of a composed real function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ and $g$ be two real functions such that the function $f$ is continuous at $x$ and the composition $f(g(x))$ is continuous at $x$. Prove that the function $g$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please include some of your own thoughts and attempts at solving this problem, so we know where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

What about if $f(x)=0$ (constant function) and $g(x)$ is any function discontinuous at $x$?

Comment: So from your answer this problem seems to be false.

Comment: @user157336 Yes, in fact if $f$ is *any* constant function, the conditions $f$ continuous and $f \circ g$ continuous are both true, since each of $f, f\circ g$ is a constant function. So these conditions don't imply anything about the function $g$ at a specific $x$ value, in particular $g$ may be discontinuous at $x$.

Comment: So,it is false. Thanks.